# How to debug “Error: Error: java.util.NoSuchElementException” in Java?

Tags: java

Code :

```
int i = MobStackHandler.this.getInstance().getConfigHandler().getMobStackingRadius();
        List localList = MobStackHandler.this.mobList;
        Iterator localIterator2;
        for (Iterator localIterator1 = Bukkit.getServer().getWorlds().iterator(); localIterator1.hasNext(); localIterator2.hasNext())
        {
          World localWorld = (World)localIterator1.next();
          localIterator2 = localWorld.getLivingEntities().iterator();
          LivingEntity localLivingEntity = (LivingEntity)localIterator2.next();
          if ((localList.contains(localLivingEntity.getType())) && (localLivingEntity.isValid())) {
            for (Entity localEntity : localLivingEntity.getNearbyEntities(i, i, i)) {
              if (((localEntity instanceof LivingEntity)) && (localEntity.isValid()) && (localList.contains(localEntity.getType()))) {
                MobStackHandler.this.stackOne(localLivingEntity, (LivingEntity)localEntity, ChatColor.valueOf(MobStackHandler.this.getInstance().getConfigHandler().getMobStackColor()));
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }.runTaskTimer(getInstance(), 40L, 40L);
  }
```

Error:      at com.obvious.handlers.MobStackHandler$1.run(MobStackHandler.java:87) ~[?:?]

Comment: why are you using a `for` loop across the `localIterator1`? It would make more sense, I think, to assign the `localIterator1` and then do `while (localIterator1.hasNext()) { ... }`. It is likely the issue is with the check of `localIterator2.hasNext()` in the loop.

Comment: If you want any help, at least tell us what is line 87 in your code?

Answer (score 0):

As [Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)

**NoSuchElementException:**

Thrown by the nextElement method of an Enumeration to indicate that there are no more elements in the enumeration.

If you want to debug just debug your iteration.

Comment: As it should be